# If in a commutative ring $R$ a maximal ideal is nilpotent, then $R$ is local

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noncommutative-algebra, local-rings

> Let $R$ a commutative ring, and $M$ a maximal ideal of $R$.
>
> If there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M^n=0$, then $R$ is local.

In general, I have proved that $R/M^n$ is local with a unique maximal ideal $M/M^n$.
But I don't see how to prove that $R$ is local.

Comment: But if $M^n=0$, then $R\simeq R/M^n$ so it seems you're done, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R$ is local is equivalent to say that $R$ has a unique maximal ideal. Let $N$ be a maximal ideal, $x\in M$, $x^n=0\in N$ implies $x\in N$ or $x^{n-1}\in N$ since $N$ is prime, we deduce recursively that $x\in N, M\subset N$ since $M$ is maximal, $M=N$.